# Is there a Simplify Curves addon for Blender 2.80?

Tags: animation

I'm using the latest Blender 2.80, and I notice a Simplify Curves addon at preferences> addons> search:simplify I see Add Curves:Simplify Curves, but then it says upgrade to 2.8x required.
What is currently the way to simplify a complex animation F-curve?
Sometimes I like to record a complex object movement, but I used to love to then Simplify the curves to various degrees with Simplify Curves addon.
Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Select your keyframes on graph editor.
Press "o" Select SMOOTH KEYS. That should "simplify" a little bit better your curves.
I remember the function "simplify curve" is available for grease pencil, but I don´t remember seeing it elsewhere. Please paste a screen capture.

I hope this works for you. If it does, please vote me up and mark me on the checkbox to the left side of this answer. 
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the smooth keys idea. Yes I have been using that for a while. I do miss  https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Simplify/ for the way it would actually remove many of the dense animation keyframes that occur with recording animation. I was just wondering if there's something else like this for Blender 2.80. Thanks again.

Comment: Please, if anyone finds a way to make this addon work with 2.8x, reply to me.